# Bit masking confusion

Tags: c

I get this result when I bitwise & -4227072 and 0x7fffff:

> 0b1111111000000000000000

These are the bit representations for the two values I'm &'ing:

> -0b10000001000000000000000
>
> 0b11111111111111111111111

Shouldn't &'ing them together instead give this?

> 0b10000001000000000000000

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-4227072 == 0xFFBF8000 == 1111 1111 1011 1111 1000 0000 0000
```

`-4227072 & 0x7fffff` should be

```
   0xFFBF8000 == 1111 1111 1011 1111 1000 0000 0000 0000
&    0x7fffff == 0000 0000 0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
   -----------------------------------------------------
   0x003F8000 == 0000 0000 0011 1111 1000 0000 0000 0000
```

Answer (score 2):

The negative number is represented as its [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) inside the computer's memory.  The binary representation you have posted is thus misleading.  In 2's complement, the most significant digit (at bit *k*) has value –2<sup>k–1</sup>.  The remaining digits are positive as you expect.

Assuming you are dealing with 32 bit signed integers, we have:

```
   1111 1111 1011 1111 1000 0000 0000 0000  =  −422707210
 & 0000 0000 0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111  =    7fffff16
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
   0000 0000 0011 1111 1000 0000 0000 0000
```

Which is what you got.

To verify the first line:

```
−1 × 231  =  −214748364810
 1 × 230  =   107374182410
 1 × 229  =    53687091210
 1 × 228  =    26843545610
 1 × 227  =    13421772810
 1 × 226  =     6710886410
 1 × 225  =     3355443210
 1 × 224  =     1677721610
 1 × 223  =      838860810
 1 × 221  =      209715210
 1 × 220  =      104857610
 1 × 219  =       52428810
 1 × 218  =       26214410
 1 × 217  =       13107210
 1 × 216  =        6553610
 1 × 215  =        3276810
——————————————————————————————
                −422707210 ✓
```

Answer (score 1):

`0b10000001000000000000000` is correct - if your integer encoding was signed-magnitude.

This is possible on some early or novel machines.  [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25817070/2410359)  well explains how negative integers are typically represented as 2's complement numbers and then the result is as you observed: `0b1111111000000000000000`.